# What are the files to upload to Web Server for a ASP.NET MVC web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have created a ASP.NET MVC site and now I need to upload it to web hosting server, for that do I have to upload whole project or only selected set of files & folders. If so what are the folders and files should I upload to the web server?

Comment: I always set my build configuration to Release and then publish to the file system or directly to an FTP. This will copy over only what is needed. Mainly you don't need to copy over any of your C# or VB code files, these will all be compiled into a single DLL that lives in the bin folder.

Comment: In past when I working in MVc project I just upload the file through FTP and tell server-admin to give that directory for exection. I changed my connectionstring in web.config that I will make never replace with my new file when I make changes. I use bin-deployment on my work and deploy many project without any hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right-click the project in Visual Studio and select Publish... This will publish the required files to a folder from where you can upload them.

A couple of points to note.

- Set the build config to Release before running Publish. This
  substitutes in the values in your Web.Release.config file which sets
  debug to false by default but you can also put in server connection
  strings and other production settings.
- Some dll's which are required will not be included in the Publish
  folder by default. To include a Referenced dll select it in the
  Reference folder and set its Copy Local property to True. It is a bit
  hit and miss figuring out which dlls are not on your server and need
  to be manually added..